# JWT validation failed: Could not find matching key in public key set for kid

Tags: jwt, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm generating a JWT using `google-auth-library-nodejs` by providing the credentials through env variables, similar to the sample code from [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs).

```
const credentials = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(env.service_account.credentials));
const client = auth.fromJSON(credentials);
const url = 'my_url';
const token = await client.fetchIdToken(url);
```

When using that token later on for authentication, the request fails because of the following error:

> JWT validation failed: Could not find matching key in public key set for kid=7da7843e8637d669bc2a12622cede2a8814d11b1

https://jwt.io/#debugger-io confirms that the kid of the generated JWT is indeed `7da7843e8637d669bc2a12622cede2a8814d11b1`, however, the private key id in the json is `6bd5b5d36f9a4225bd814ff3d6909d95e23e0793`.

Here's the json

```
'{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "private_key_id": "6bd5b5d36f9a4225bd814ff3d6909d95e23e0793",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my_service_account@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "REDACTED",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my_service_account%40project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Should the kid match the privat_key_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client_x509_cert_url` provided in the question above was not the right `x-google-jwks_uri`. It actually has to be `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs`.

After changing the URI, the `kid`s match.

If anyone has a clue why that is, it would be much appreciated.